# Razor WebSite - Defining Layout in _PageStart, RenderSection stops working

Tags: templates, layout, razor

I'm defining my Layout in _PageStart.cshtml for all templates.
In my template file, like home.cshtml, the RenderSection is ignored.

**_PageStart.cshtml**

```
Layout = "~/template/_Layout.cshtml";
RunPage();
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
@RenderSection("css", required: false)
...
@RenderBody()
...
```

**home.cshtml**

```
@section css{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
}
...
```

Only RenderSection is ignored, _Layout.cshtml is correctly loaded.
If specific the Layout in home.cshtml, RenderSection works.
Can anyone help me ?